# Difference between local and dense layers in CNNs

Tags: python, convolution, deep-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between a "Local" layer and a "Dense" layer in a convolutional neural network?  I am trying to understand the CIFAR-10 code in TensorFlow, and I see it uses "Local" layers instead of regular dense layers. Is there any class in TF that supports implementing "Local" layers?

Comment: maybe densely connected? That's just regular "fully connected layer". I don't see any reference to "local" layer in https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Comment: You can find the local layers in the CIFAR-10 sample code, under tutorials.

Comment: The tutorial says: "EXERCISE: The model architecture in inference() differs slightly from the CIFAR-10 model specified in cuda-convnet. In particular, the top layers of Alex's original model are locally connected and not fully connected. Try editing the architecture to exactly reproduce the locally connected architecture in the top layer."

Comment: A convolutional layer strikes me as an example of a locally connected layer, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, but then isn't it that a locally connected layer becomes like the "convolutional" layer? As I understand, either it should be densely connected or be a convolutional layer ...

Comment: The [post: understanding-locally-connected-layers-in-convolutional-neural-networks](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/04/12/understanding-locally-connected-layers-in-convolutional-neural-networks/) wrotten by [Prateek Joshi](https://prateekvjoshi.com) is really helpful for you to understand the locally connected layers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [cuda-convnet](https://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/wiki/LayerParams#Locally-connected_layer_with_unshared_weights):

> Locally-connected layer with unshared-weight: This kind of layer is just like a convolutional layer, but without any weight-sharing. That is to say, a different set of filters is applied at every (x, y) location in the input image. Aside from that, it behaves exactly as a convolutional layer.

In the TensorFlow CIFAR-10 example, although the two layers are named `local3` and `local4`, they are actually fully-connected layer, not locally-connected layer as specified in [cuda-convnet](https://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/wiki/LayerParams#Locally-connected_layer_with_unshared_weights) (you can see that the output from `pool2` is flattened into the input of `local3` layer).

Answer (score 4):

I am quoting user2576346's comments under the question:

> As I understand, either it should be densely connected or be a convolutional layer ...

No this is not true. A more accurate way to phrase that statement would be that layers are either fully connected (dense) or locally connected.

A convolutional layer is an example of a locally connected layer. In general a locally connected layer is a layer in which each of its units is only connected to a local portion of the input. A convolutional layer is a special type of local layer which exhibits a spatial translation invariance as each convolutional feature detector is strided across the entire image in local receptive windows, e.g. of size 3x3 or 5x5 for example.